# Rust trait objects: specific use case of variance and/or coercion

Tags: rust, variance, coercion, trait-objects

Consider the following ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=64fa54ccc46445253484feab52026a57))

```rust
trait Module {}

struct Foo {
    module_box: Box<dyn Module + 'static>,
    module_rc: Rc<dyn Module + 'static>,
}

impl Foo {
    fn mut_box<'s>(&'s mut self) -> &'s mut (dyn Module + 's) {
        // this works
        self.module_box.as_mut() // : &'s mut (dyn Module + 'static)
    }

    fn mut_rc<'s>(&'s mut self) -> Option<&'s mut (dyn Module + 's)> {
        // this doesn't work
        Rc::get_mut(&mut self.module_rc) // : Option<&'s mut (dyn Module + 'static)>
        
        // but this does
//      match Rc::get_mut(&mut self.module_rc) {
//        Some(m) => Some(m),
//        None => None,
//      }
    }
}
```

> Note: I will use `<:` to denote a subtype relationship

I have 2 related questions:

1. why does the `mut_box()` implementation work?
2. why doesn't the `mut_rc()` implement work?

For (1), I first assumed that subtyping/variance was the reason, since `(dyn Module + 'static) <: (dyn Module + 's)` (although I wasn't able to 100% confirm). However, [according to the reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/subtyping.html#variance), `&'a mut T` is *invariant* over `T`; so if I'm reading this correctly, `&'s mut (dyn Module + 'static)` is NOT a subtype of `&'s mut (dyn Module + 's)`. I then thought maybe an implicit coercion could then explain why it compiled, but was not able to find one in the [list of coercion types](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/type-coercions.html#coercion-types).

Question (2) is very similar, except that the whole thing is wrapped in an `Option`, which seems to be the reason why it fails; the commented-out code unwraps the `Option`, which I believe sends us back to (1).

Comment: This is mysterious indeed. It looks like none of these variations should work, so the main question is why some of the actually do.

Comment: I don't have time to dig into that now, but maybe it is reborrowing?

Comment: Reborrowing shouldn't be able to coerce incompatible types. I really can't understand why this works. I don't think it's a soundsness problem, but neither do I think the rules of the language as documented allow for this.